# returning the ArrayList cast to List vs no casting

Tags: java, list, arraylist, casting

What is the difference, if any, between the two:

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "attendanceStatuses")
public List<Code> getAttendanceStatusCodes() {
    List<Code> attendanceStatuses= new ArrayList<Code>(
      cacheService.getValidCodesOfCodeGroup(CODE_GROUP));
    return attendanceStatuses;
}
```

and

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "attendanceStatuses")
public List<Code> getAttendanceStatusCodes() {
    return cacheService.getValidCodesOfCodeGroup(CODE_GROUP);
}
```

The cacheService method is:

```
List<Code> getValidCodesOfCodeGroup(CodeGroupName codeGroupName);
```

Comment: regarding the question's title: there is no casting involved here. Passing an existing `List` to the constructor of `ArrayList` creates a copy of that list, that has nothign to do with casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet returns a copy of the `List` returned by `cacheService.getValidCodesOfCodeGroup(CODE_GROUP)`:

```
new ArrayList<Code>(cacheService.getValidCodesOfCodeGroup(CODE_GROUP))
```

The second snippet does not - it simply returns `cacheService.getValidCodesOfCodeGroup(CODE_GROUP)`.

There is no casting in any of these snippets though.

Note that assigning the `List` to a local variable before returning it makes no difference. You can change the first snippet to:

```
public List<Code> getAttendanceStatusCodes() {
    return new ArrayList<Code>(cacheService.getValidCodesOfCodeGroup(CODE_GROUP));
}
```

without changing the behavior.